# Check if x months have passed in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a budgeting application that sets a budget for n months how can the application know if n months have passed and to unapply the budget? How does mvc automatically check?

Comment: Why would ASP.NET MVC know to check _anything_? Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @JohnSaunders : Of course MVC wouldn't know, that is why I would recommend using WebForms instead :)

Comment: I don't get what the OP means by "how does mvc automatically check?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steve's answers above make a simple example of doing that. If you want to make it automatically, you should put it on some services and call it from a scheduler or some services like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) or [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

```
(DateTime.Now - StartDate)
```

If this validation has something to do with sending an email notification and so on, I prefer check it from Database and make an SQL job to run it every day or anytime you think its fit in.

Comment: so the application should rely on some local system scheduler on the server side to automatically check each day using that validation method? that that makes sense yeah.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only way you can do it, if you want to make it run automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're saving the date the budget starts:

> (DateTime.Now - StartDate)

Will give you a result as a [Timespan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from which you can get the time in several formats.

Comment: would there be an action that automatically calls itself each day or some interval to check if n months have passed by?

Comment: You could look into Timers as RLS said, making sure it's asynchronous so it doesn't block anything else from executing. Alternatively, look into a scheduling technology like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) which will give you much more fine grained control.

Comment: Yeah awesome thanks to you and the others I have an idea of how to get started solving that problem. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to up your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using the Timers class asynchronously on the server. This would mean that the service would need to remain up for x months. Your best choice would most likely be to persist the end date and trigger a timer to call a function when that date condition is true.

```
//Timer set to run every 20 seconds    
Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(20000);
            //Timer set to run every 20 seconds
            Timer.Elapsed += SendTimerElapsed;
            Timer.Start();
```

Heres an example:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        t.Elapsed += Hitme;
        t.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Hitme(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ouch");
    }
}
```